# Shortening a String Haskell

Tags: haskell

How do you shorten a string in Haskell with a given number.

Say:

```
comp :: String -> String
short :: String -> String

chomp (x:xs) = (x : takeWhile (==x) xs)
```

using `comp` I want to select a run of repeated characters from the start of a string, with 
the run comprising at most nine characters.

For example:

`short "aaaavvvdd"`
would output `"aaaa"`
and `short "dddddddddd"`
outputs `"ddddddddd"`.

I know I need `take` but am not sure how to put that into the code.

i've got this far but it doesn't work

```
short x:xs | length(short x:xs) >9 = take(9)
           | otherwise = comp
```

Comment: is this homework? if so please add the homework tag.

Comment: no, i'm just bored and have decided to teach myself haskell

Comment: Your definition is pretty good so far, you are just struggling with syntax.  Here's what I think you were trying to write: `short xs | length (chomp xs) > 9 = take 9 xs | otherwise = chomp xs`.  Not the most efficient thing in the world, but it will get you started.

Answer (score 9):

### The Quick Answer

```
import Data.List
short [] = []
short x = (take 9 . head . group) x
```

This will give you output that matches your desired output.

That is,

```
*> short "aaaavvvdd"
"aaaa"
*> short "dddddddddd"
"ddddddddd"
```

---

### Step by Step Development

#### Use "group" to separate the items

This solution depends on the "group" function in the Data.List library.  We begin with the definition:

```
short x = group x
```

This gives us:

```
*> short "aaaavvvddd"
["aaaa","vvv","ddd"]
```

#### Use "head" to return only the first element

Once we have the the elements in a list, we want only the first item of the list.  We achieve this using "head":

```
short x = (head . group) x
```

"." is the Haskell function for function composition.  It's the same as:

```
short x = head (group x)
```

or

```
short x = head $ group x
```

This will give us:

```
*> short "aaaavvvdd"
"aaaa"
*> short "dddddddddddddd"
"dddddddddddddd"
```

#### Use "take" to get the first nine characters

We finish the program by taking only the first nine characters of this result, and end up with our final function.  To do this, we use the "take" function from the prelude:

```
short x = (take 9 . head . group) x
```

We now have the result that we wanted, but with one minor problem.

#### Add another case to eliminate the error

Note that using our current definition on the empty list causes an error,

```
*> short "aaaavvvddd"
"aaaa"
*> short ""
"*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

Because "head" is undefined on the empty list, we need to handle another case: the empty list.  Now we have:

```
short [] = []
short x = (take 9 . head . group) x
```

This is our "final answer".

Answer (score 4):

Here is another version:

```
short xs = take 9 $ takeWhile (== head xs) xs
```

So we take from the list as long as the content equals the head of list (which is the first char of the string). Then we use `take` to shorten the result when necessary.

Note that we *don't* need an additional case for empty strings, which is a consequence from Haskell's lazyness: If `takeWhile` sees that the list argument is empty, it doesn't bother to evaluate the condition argument, so `head xs` doesn't throw an error.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a definition:

```
import Data.List (group)
short = take 9 . head . group
```

Interestingly enough, since our returned string is a prefix of the original string, and is constrained to be at most 9 characters long, it doesn't matter whether we trim down to that limit first or last.  So we could also use this definition:

```
short = head . group . take 9
```

Both of these are written in the "pointfree" style which doesn't reference a lack of punctuation, but a lack of unnecessary variables.  We could have also written the definition as

```
short s = take 9 (head (group s))
```

Or, using `$` to get rid of parentheses:

```
short s = take 9 $ head $ group s
```

The only other step is to extract only the first block of matching characters, which is what `head . group` does (equivalent to your `chomp` function).

From [the docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3agroup):

> ```
> group :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
> ```
>
> The `group` function takes a list and returns a list of lists such that the concatenation of the result is equal to the argument. Moreover, each sublist in the result contains only equal elements. For example,
>
> ```
> group "Mississippi" = ["M","i","ss","i","ss","i","pp","i"]
> ```
>
> It is a special case of `groupBy`, which allows the programmer to supply their own equality test.